# MVC ajax not downloading a file

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

This is the ajax call which is calling the controller

```
 @using(Html.BeginForm("ExportData", "ViewData", FormMethod.Post,
     new {
         id = "myform", name = "myform"
     })) {


     <button type = "submit"> Export Raw Policy </button>
 }


 <div id = "divProcessing"> <img src = ~/assets/layouts/layout3/img/loading-spinner-blue.gif" > </p> </div>


 @section Scripts {
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

     <script type = "text/javascript" >

         $(document)
         .ready(function() {

             // Hide the "busy" Gif at load:
             $("#divProcessing").hide();

             // Handle the form submit event, and make the Ajax request:
             $("#myform")
                 .on("submit",
                     function(event) {
                         event.preventDefault();

                         // Show the "busy" Gif:
                         $("#divProcessing").show();
                         var url = $(this).attr("action");
                         var formData = $(this).serialize();
                         $.ajax({
                             url: url,
                             type: "POST",
                             data: formData,
                             dataType: "json",
                             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                             success: function(resp) {

                                 // Hide the "busy" gif:
                                 $("#divProcessing").hide();

                                 // Do something useful with the data:
                                 $("<h3></h3>")
                                     .appendTo("#divResult");
                             }
                         })
                     });
         }); </script>
 }
```

This method is exporting the datatable into excel

```
  public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable table)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(@"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"">");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Reports.xls");

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
                //sets font
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<font style='font-size:10.0pt; font-family:Calibri;'>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<BR><BR><BR>");
                //sets the table border, cell spacing, border color, font of the text, background, foreground, font height
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Table border='1' bgColor='#ffffff' " +
                                                   "borderColor='#000000' cellSpacing='0' cellPadding='0' " +
                                                   "style='font-size:11.0pt; font-family:Calibri; background:white;'> <TR>");
                //am getting my grid's column headers
                int columnscount = table.Columns.Count;

                for (int j = 0; j < columnscount; j++)
                {
                    //write in new column
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                    //Get column headers  and make it as bold in excel columns
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<B>");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(table.Columns[j].ToString());
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</B>");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
//write in new row
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<TR>");
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<Td>");
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(row[i].ToString()));
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Td>");
                    }

                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</TR>");
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</Table>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</font>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string abc = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

This is my controller

```
 public ActionResult ExportData()
        {
            var industryData = _rawDataHlper.GetIndustryData();
            if (industryData != null)
            {
                ExportToExcel((industryData));
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The above code is making an ajax call and calling a controller. The controller is downloading datatable into excel.

If i call the controller without ajax call then it will download the excel file but when i am making the ajax call then it is not downloading the excel file.

The code is calling the correct controller and action but it is not downloading the file.

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong here. It works fine without ajax.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dataType: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.` declared on the [documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) Just remove it.

Comment: Yup i tried by removing that but still does not work

Comment: I searched a little bit and as @madalin said you are not able to do it with ajax. Ajax doesn't let you download file to your computer. [other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redirect in a ajax call better if you return a url to the resource append that url to a download link and trigger the click for the download to start

return a link from c#

```
return LinkToAction("Index");// don't know the syntax here sorry
```

create a link in the success function

```
 success: function(resp) {
  $('body').append('<a  class="hidden-download" href="'+resp+'" download>hidden<a>').trigger('click').hide();//append it to the body, trigger the click then hide/remove the link
```

Comment: The problem is that i dont have any download link. I am creating a datatable and passing that to export to excel function which is downloading the file. So i should pass the datatable from controller to ajax success and from there i should pass that datatable back to controller to call the export to excel method?

Comment: from what i can understand ExportToExcel is creating a page with datatable , use the url of that generated page

Comment: I cannot find any url in HttpContext.Current.Response.

Comment: create a route to ExportToExcel return that route in ExportData

Comment: sorry i am new to mvc what do you mean by creating a route?

Comment: you don't know what a route is ?, i am not familiar with mvc

Comment: a route is the link/url to the result of that function

Comment: I tried to find the url in                 HttpContext.Current.Response but could not find anything. Any idea how to create a route?